# Run iPython on Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: python, windows-8, ipython

I am trying to run iPython on my Windows 8. I installed python 3.4.0 (32 bit version) and successfully installed iPython through the command

```
easy_install ipython[all]
```

The problem is when I try to run it

```
ipython notebook
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('ipython==3.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 573, in launch_instance app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 369, in initialize self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 30, in <module> check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 10, in check_for_zmq import zmq
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 25, in <module> _libsodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled_sodium[0])
File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary     return self._dlltype(name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) 
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Probably the 'name' of some application is wrongly specified. Can you help me to understand how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy_Install is the devil (IMHO). You might want to use Continuum [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). The Continuum solution is one that simply "just works" and helps to avoid the many hassles you will most likely have later with Easy_Install.

Comment: I just installed Anaconda and when I run ipython I get the error:

    Failed to creat process

Comment: Ok It works if I launch it from the Anaconda cmd prompt! Thanks!